# How to view output of /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily after apt-daily.service is run by systemd?

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, email, debugging

In /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily it reads that

> #  APT::Periodic::Verbose "0";
>
> #  - Send report mail to root
>
> #      0:  no report             (or null string)
>
> #      1:  progress report       (actually any string)
>
> #      2:  + command outputs     (remove -qq, remove 2>/dev/null, add -
>   d)
>
> #      3:  + trace on

I have set

```
APT::Periodic::Verbose "3";
```

in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic. I have set up `ssmtp` to be able to send mails, and it seems to work, but I don't seem to get mails about the script's output.

Comment: BTW In Xenial it does not output as documented in case "APT::Periodic::Verbose 2", see [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=845599)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail reporting may work by cron system which was used before, but not with systemd.

The output can be seen in systemd journal

```
journalctl -u apt-daily.service
```

Comment: it seems this information is lost after reboot, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @Plumpie https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1618188

Comment: journald with `Storage=auto` (the default) will persist logs the target dir exists. Just run `mkdir /var/log/journal && systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal && systemctl restart systemd-journald `